# What do jars outside brackets denote in this IntelliJ Search

Tags: java, intellij-idea

The search for a class file in IntelliJ shows 2 jars for each entry, The class is actually contained in the jar shown in bracket but what does the jar file outside bracket (xalan.jar in this case) denotes?

[image: IntelliJ class file search dialog]

Comment: Can you see either `xalan.jar` or `xmlbeans-4.0.0.jar` in your depedency list on the left side of your project window?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Yes, both of them are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you search all files, not exclusively for class files.

Usually, IntelliJ search tab, that you are pointing at, shows the full name of the dependency (`xalan.jar`, in your case), followed by the actual `.jar` file, in the braces, that comes from the dependency written before braces, and that contains your search term. Beware, that one dependency may obtain and download several .jar files.

I'm not sure why you have only `xalan` (without groupId, and version), but reason can be the way, you declare your dependencies.